# Compiling a DLL in Visual Studio Express for use in a VB Script

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2010, vbscript

I am looking at converting a DLL written in VB into C++. The dll gets called as part of a login script to perform various functions.

My C++ is a bit rusty, and i've only got Visual C++ Express. I can create a DLL ok from C++, but i cant register it using regsvr32.

I'm assuming I need to include something in the build options to make in COM aware, but i'm not sure what.

My other option is calling a non com dll from vbscript somehow. Any ideas about this?

Cheers
Luke

Answer (score 1):

You need a COM Callable Wrapper (CCW). Searching MSDN for this term should provide you with enough of a start to get going.